# Randomly select n rows from a dataframe t times?

Tags: pandas, random

How can I randomly select n rows from a dataframe t times?

For example: I have a dataframe df with 10 rows and I want to get 3 rows a time and repeat it 10 time.

```
a   value
n1  0.1
n2  0.2
n3  0.3
n4  0.4
n5  0.5
n6  0.6
n7  0.7
n8  0.8
n9  0.9
n10 1
```

```
Output
n1  0.1
n2  0.2
n3  0.3

n3  0.3
n5  0.5
n6  0.6

n1  0.1
n4  0.4
n3  0.3

n2  0.2
n4  0.4
n6  0.6

and so on...
```

In the end, I want to plot the score columns of these 10 small dataframes with another dataframe.

Till now, I have used the below function. But I do not know how to get the samples n times.

```
df_elements = df.sample(n=3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
df_elements = [x.sample(n=3) for i in range(10)]
```

If want join them together use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat(df_elements, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will store `n` dataframes in a dictionary so that you can access them:

```
# Initialize dictionary
samples={}

# Store n samples
for i in range(1,n+1):
    samples[i] = df.sample(frac=0.3)
```

In this way you will be able to access the `i-th` sample by `samples[i]`